# mobile development tools using HTML5 and C++

Tags: javascript, c++, html, mobile, cross-platform

I want to find a cross platform mobile development tool that support both Android and iOS. I have some CPU-intensive code in C++, and I want to use HTML5 as my GUI part. I know MoSync can provide a bridge for C++ and HTML5+JavaScript for mobile apps. But besides MoSync, are there any other tools that can integrate code in C++ and HTML+JavaScript. I need to integrate the code of C++/HTML/JavaScript and let code communicate between C++ side and JavaScript side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) can help you here. Qt is cross platform and there are even ports for [Android](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/android-lighthouse) and [iPhone](http://www.qt-iphone.com/Introduction.html) available.

take a look specially at those Qt-moduls:

- **QtScrip** (javascript)
- **QtWebkit** (Html rendering, Html 5 supportet since Qt 5)

---

***Documentation:** (abridgement)*

- [Qt (general)](http://qt-project.org/doc/)
- [Qt 5.0](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/index.html) and [Qt 4.8](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/)
- [QtMobility](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category%3aDeveloping_with_Qt%3a%3aQtMobility)
- [Scripting](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/topics-scripting.html)

  - [QtScript](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtscript/qtscript-module.html)
  - [JS Engine](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qjsengine.html)
  - [Use Case - Integrating JavaScript in QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-usecase-integratingjs.html) ([QML)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-index.html)
  - [ECMA Script](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtscript/ecmascript.html)
- [Examples / Demos / Tutorials](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qtexamplesandtutorials.html)

  - [Rich Text Exammples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/examples-richtext.html)
  - [Qt WebKit Widgets Examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkitexamples/webkit-widgetexamples.html)
  - [Qt Webkit Examples and Demos](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkitexamples/webkit-qmlexamples.html)

---

> **Mobile platforms**
>
> Qt 5 will support all leading mobile operating systems. There already
>   exists work in progress support for:
>
> - Android
> - iOS
> - Windows 8 (WinRT)
> - BlackBerry 10

*( source: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/supported-platforms.html )*

Comment: Thanks for the info. So for the Qt iOS support, is it full functioning right now? Also is QtScript essentially the same as JavaScript? I have some C++ code and some HTML5/JavaScript code that I want to integrate with for both Android and iOS. Is it possible to seamlessly integrate C++ with HTML5/JavaScript using the Qt suite?

Comment: I havent uses Qt for mobile devices yet, so unfortunately i can only refer you to the documentation. I add some more links to may answer - hope they can help you.

Comment: _So for the Qt iOS support, is it full functioning right now?_ Seems Qt5 supports those plattforms (independend from ports mentions before?), and is ready for use (but not 100% finished yet). However i guess it's ready for use - if possible give it a try.

Comment: The documentation is very detailed. Thanks a lot.